# SheetViews is null trying to freeze rows openXML

Tags: c#, openxml

trying to reference this link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e1c08add-b610-44c9-b60e-fa8ef6c24978/openxmlexcelc?forum=oxmlsdk

I am getting a sheetview null pointer exception on this line:

SheetView sw = wsp.Worksheet.SheetViews.FirstOrDefault() asSheetView;

I am not using any sheetviews when creating my spreadsheet, and I am using memorystream to pass back to use.

Using this code:

How would I freeze the top two rows? Thanks!

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

        WorkbookPart wbp = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
        WorksheetPart wsp = wbp.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        Workbook wb = new Workbook();
        FileVersion fv = new FileVersion();
        fv.ApplicationName = "Microsoft Office Excel";
        Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();

        SheetData sd = new SheetData();

        WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = xl.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStyleSheet();
        stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();




        //create header
        uint colHeaderIndex = 1;
        Row r1 = new Row() { RowIndex = colHeaderIndex };
        foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(list[0]))
        {
            Cell headerCell = new Cell();
            headerCell.DataType = CellValues.String;
            headerCell.CellValue = new CellValue(descriptor.DisplayName);
            r1.Append(headerCell);
        }
        //append header row to sheet
        sd.Append(r1);


        //now fill the rest of the rows with data
        uint rowIndex = 1; //Start at 1, since we reserved index 1 for the heading. The indexer will increase its value by 1 before it is used.  
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            uint colIndex = 1;
            Row row = new Row() { RowIndex = ++rowIndex };
            foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor descriptor in System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(list[i]))
            {
                Cell cell = new Cell();
                cell.CellReference = rowIndex + " x " + colIndex;
                cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                cell.StyleIndex = 1;
                var val = descriptor.GetValue(list[i]);
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(val != null ? val.ToString() : "");
                row.Append(cell);
            }

            //append data row to sheet
            sd.Append(row);
        }

        ws.Append(sd);
        wsp.Worksheet = ws;
        wsp.Worksheet.Save();
        Sheets sheets = new Sheets();
        Sheet sheet = new Sheet();
        sheet.Name = "first sheet";
        sheet.SheetId = 1; //we will only have one sheet for now, unless we are maxing out on sheets then we can create new ones
        sheet.Id = wbp.GetIdOfPart(wsp);
        sheets.Append(sheet);
        wb.Append(fv);
        wb.Append(sheets);
        freezeHeader(wbp, wsp);
        xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook = wb;
        xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        xl.Close();

        Response.Clear();
        byte[] dt = ms.ToArray();

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}.xlsx", fileName));
        Response.BinaryWrite(dt);
        Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out by using the open XML SDK 2.0 productivity tool.. apparently order of appending to the worksheet is a big deal. So I did need to create a new SheetViews list and SheetView, but the SheetViews list need to be appended to the worksheet before the data sheet was.

so adding,

```
    SheetViews sheetViews1 = new SheetViews();

    SheetView sheetView1 = new SheetView() { TabSelected = true, WorkbookViewId = (UInt32Value)0U };
    Pane pane1 = new Pane() { VerticalSplit = 1D, TopLeftCell = "A2", ActivePane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, State = PaneStateValues.Frozen };
    Selection selection1 = new Selection() { Pane = PaneValues.BottomLeft, ActiveCell = "A2", SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "A2:XFD2" } };

    sheetView1.Append(pane1);
    sheetView1.Append(selection1);

    sheetViews1.Append(sheetView1);
```

and calling

```
ws.Append(sheetViews1);
```

right before,

```
ws.Append(sd);
```

worked. If I appended after sheetdata (sd) was already appended then the file would become corrupt due to the error it was throwing; which I was able to see using the productivity tool.

Using the tool, I was able to first print my Excel sheet using my working code (before trying to Freeze header row) then I froze the header row manually inside excel and resaved the file. I opened this new file up inside the tool, and i was able to view the code used to create the document and saw the order of the appending.

Hope this helps someone. I was able to see a few other questions like these with no solution (or follow up).